# Where is a good resources for all the Javascript APIs for HTML5

Tags: javascript, api, video, documentation, html

I'm looking for a reference that summarizes all of the available Javascript APIs that are introduced with HTML 5, for each browser that has implemented any of the new features. Does something like this exist? If nothing else, then at least the VIDEO tag

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some official stuff is here: http://dev.w3.org/html5/html4-differences/#apis. A site with some sweet demos of the new features is here though: http://html5demos.com/ (You can view source to see the code). The resource that Marcel pointed out is also a good one.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at the last [**Working Draft**](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/) of HTML 5, specifically the section about the [`<video>` **element**](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/video.html#video). It contains some samples of Javascript.

But remember that it is of course still a working draft and liable to change. Moreover, as history shows browsers can have different implementations of what the specs say. In the Working Draft there are yellow annotations regarding browser support.

Furthermore, you can read the specifications of [ECMAScript 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), to see what browsers **may** support (but this has nothing to do with HTML5 as such).

Comment: The WHATWG even has browser compaibility info in the annotations on the left.

Comment: @Nickolay: thanks, edited. How could I have missed them? Banner blindness, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the documentation others have provided, you may want to look at [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/). This small script will let you specify CSS and JS fallbacks for any HTML5 attributes that are not consistently supported across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Shameless self promotion, but you might want to take a look at [simpl.info](http://simpl.info), which has simplest possible examples of HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

There's a lot of 'HTML5' stuff: [getUserMedia()](http://simpl.info/getusermedia/), [WebRTC](http://simpl.info/pc) [CSS filters](http://simpl.info/cssfilters/), [Resource Timing](http://simpl.info/resourcetiming/), [speech recognition](https://simpl.info/stt/), [MutationObserver](http://simpl.info/mutationobserver/) and lots more.